# Deleting an employee record from multiple tables in a database

Tags: database, db2

I am having a database where i am having employee id's.

And some how the employee details are having relationship with multiple tables. Now I need to delete all the data from all the tables specific to an employee id.

In a clear way what i want is i need to remove the employee and its associated data from the database.

There are many tables and i can't check all the tables how the employee was associated. Is there any solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Does your database have foreign keys?  Is there documentation (like an E-R diagram and related architecture documentation) for the database that tells you all of the tables that are related to employee?

Without proper documentation, you could *guess* (based on table and column names), or by going through all application code that accesses the database to try to determine the relationships.  Neither of these options are particularly helpful, and may result in missed relationships.

Comment: Yes mine having foreign keys. And i don't have application code. I only have access details.